# Concatenating binary bits into a number

Tags: matlab

I want to concatenate last four bits of binary into a number i have tried the following code

```
x8=magic(4)
x8_n=dec2bin(x8)
m=x8_n-'0'
```

which gives me the following output 
    m =

```
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     1
     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     1     1
     0     0     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     0     1     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1     0
     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     0     1
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
```

now i want to take every last 4 bits it each row and convert it into an integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 4; %// number of bits you want
result = m(:,end-n+1:end) * pow2(n-1:-1:0).'; %'// matrix multiplication
```

Anyway, it would be easier to use [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) on `x8` directly, without the intermediate step of `m`:

```
result = mod(x8(:), 2^n);
```

In your example:

```
result =
     0
     5
     9
     4
     2
    11
     7
    14
     3
    10
     6
    15
    13
     8
    12
     1
```

Comment: +1 for a complete answer BTW :) OP won't need all those three lines to get to `m`

Answer (score 2):

This could be another approach -

```
n = 4; %%// number of bits you want
out = bin2dec(num2str(m(:,end-n+1:end)))
```

Output -

```
out =

     0
     5
     9
     4
     2
    11
     7
    14
     3
    10
     6
    15
    13
     8
    12
     1
```

Comment: Or, more simply, `out = bin2dec(x8_n(:,end-n+1:end))` :-) +1

Comment: what if i want to take the middle two bits of the m array ?

Comment: This must work for that case - `out = bin2dec(num2str(m(:,3:4)))`. It's all about manipulating the second index of `m`, which denotes the  column number(s).